# Grid View Formatting

Tags: asp.net, css

I need the totals below each other in the footer template. There should be no gridlines after the rows with data until the 5th column, and then again a gridline after the Total Col.

Here's the ASPX Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="AliceBlue"
ShowFooter="True" EnableModelValidation="True" 
    onrowdatabound="LineItemGrid_RowDataBound" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" CellSpacing="0"
   style="border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-weight:bold;width:1050px;"> 
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="xxx">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='Label' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="yyyy">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text='Label' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

     ///....Two other template fields here....
 </asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbltotal" runat="server" Text='' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttotalprice" ReadOnly="true" Width="100px" BorderStyle="None" ></asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Pleaes help me how do I apply the formatting as required below in the footer template....

Comment: It does not seem to me that you are in need of paging, sorting or any specific Gridview function. In that case, why don't you just build your own HTML table and design it the way you are required to do so? Just a thought.

Comment: Paging would be included

Comment: It's not so simple. What you should look at is the GridView_RowDataBound event. Everytime a row is bound, this event is fired, and, from the passed Row object, you can access the cells. You can then loop through each cell and set a CSS style. It might be easier to use a different type of control, though, as you say, you may want paging etc

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the GridView_RowDataBound event

You could then do something like:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
     {
       if(i > 5)
       {
         e.Row.Cells[i].CssClass = "CellBorder";    
       }
     }

  }

}
```

You'll need to play with the indexing and conditions (and the CSS!)